# (boost/std)::bind шаблонной наследуемой и перегруженной функции

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, stl, c++14

Есть следующий тестовый пример:

```
struct Test {
    template <typename T>
    void testing(T&& t) {}
};

struct Implement : Test<Implement> 
{
    typedef Test<Implement> base_t;
    template <typename T>
    void testing(T&&t) 
    {
        auto binder = ::boost::bind(&base_t:: template testing<T>, static_cast<base_t*>(this), ::std::forward<T>(t));
        binder();
    }
};
```

Вызов `Implement::testing(*rvalue*);` приводит к остановке компиляции с ошибкой `operator __surrogate_func не соответствующая перегруженная функция` на строке вызова `binder()`.

Boost дает более осмысленное описание ошибки о невозможности преобразовать параметр: `Error C2664   'R boost::_mfi::mf1<R,Test<Implement>,T &&>::operator ()(Test<Implement> *,A1) const': cannot convert argument 2 from 'T' to 'A1'`.

Вызвать метод напрямую могу. MSVC 2017 последней ревизии. А вот в чем ошибка заключается понять не могу пока что.

**Дополнение:** Как всегда мысль приходит опосля. Rvalue он не хочет принимать, хотя я думал (Точнее принимает, но в вызов непосредственно функции он передает параметр уже как lvalue), раз std::bind может использовать move, значит скорее всего есть перегрузка для rvalue. Это не так( Если создать `int i = 0;` и передать в функцию, то все нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объекты, создаваемые `std::bind`, как и объекты `std::thread`, рассчитаны на "долговременное" существование, т.е. в т.ч. на выход за пределы времени жизни переданных аргументов. По этой причине объекты `std::bind` всегда создают и хранят в себе *копии* переданных аргументов, независимо от того, являлся ли фактический аргумент ссылкой. При последующем вызове целевой функции в качестве аргумента будет выступать именно внутренняя копия, которая всегда является lvalue.

`std::bind`, как и `std::thread`, несовместимы с концепцией "сквозного" идеального форвардинга в общем и перемещения в частности. В последнем таятся определенные подводные камни. Эта тонкость затрагивает и lvalue-ссылки, но для lvalue-ссылок сделано исключение: вам предоставлен механизм `std::reference_wrapper/std::ref/std::cref` позволяющий сохранять семантику lvalue-ссылок в рамках `std::bind` по вашему явному запросу. Для rvalue-ссылок аналога нет.

Поэтому доступные вам в данной ситуации варианты таковы

- Смириться c общими дизайн-принципами `std::bind`, отказаться от идеального форвардинга и помнить, что функция будет вызываться с lvalue-аргументом

  ```
   auto binder = std::bind(&base_t::template testing<T &>, ...
                                                       ^
  ```
- Продолжить сражаться за свои намерения и написать аналог `std::reference_wrapper` для rvalue-ссылок самостоятельно
- Отказаться от использования `std::bind` вообще и воспользоваться лямбдами, которые в этом отношении предоставляют более гибкие возможности

  ```
  ...
  void testing(T &&t) 
  {
    auto binder = [this, &t] () { base_t::testing(std::forward<T>(t)); };
    binder();
  }
  ...
  ```

Comment: Была мысль про `std::reference_wrapper`, может быть попробую

Comment: В частности, это была одна из проблем. Я передавал с помощью `move` binder в лямбду и пытался вызвать. До этого никогда с mutable lambda не сталкивался...