# (boost/std)::bind шаблонной наследуемой и перегруженной функции (Продолжение)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

Продолжение вчерашнего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946300/boost-stdbind-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), а именно про обход `bind` с целью идеальной пересылки.

Вот пример одного из решений:

```
template <typename Impl>
struct Test {
    template <typename Handle>
    void testing(Handle&& handle) {}
};

struct Implement : Test<Implement> 
{
    typedef Test<Implement> base_t;
    template <typename Handle>
    void testing(Handle&& handle)
    {

        ::std::mem_fn(&base_t:: template testing<Handle>)(static_cast<base_t*>(this), ::std::forward<Handle>(handle));

        auto generate_lambda = [](auto&& fn, auto&&...args) // 1 лямбда
        {
            ::std::mem_fn(::std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn))(::std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

            return [fn = ::std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn), tuple = ::std::make_tuple(::std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)]() mutable -> decltype(auto) // 2 лямбда
            {
                ::std::apply
                (
                    ::std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn), 
                    ::std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple)
                );
            };
        };
        auto lambda = generate_lambda( &base_t:: template testing<Handle>, static_cast<base_t*>(this), ::std::forward<Handle>(handle));
        lambda();
    }
};

int main() {

    Implement impl;
    impl.testing([]() {});
}
```

Проблема в том, что компилятор не может (или не хочет, кто его знает) найти перегрузку `::std::invoke` для заданной функции, хотя `::std::mem_fn` успешно создает биндер и выполняет функцию до второй вложенной лямбды. Пробовал создавать свою версию apply и invoke, но без успеха. Что именно здесь является неправильным?

**Уточнение:** Компилятор соглашается принимать только rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, как всегда.

> *Напиши в stackoverflow и все само решится. @MrBin.*

`::std::make_tuple` возвращает `::std::tuple<Types...>` вместо нужного мне `::std::tuple<Types&&...>`. Надо использовать `::std::forward_as_tuple`.